# Binary search tree python with OOP

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to understand python and OOP along with data structures 
I'm now looking at the implementation of a binary search tree 
here is the class for the node structure

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
```

the developer of this code has created the insert feature in Node class and in another class called tree 
here is what it looks like in the node class :

```
def insert(self, data):
    if self.data == data:
        return False        

    elif data < self.data:
        if self.leftChild:
            return self.leftChild.insert(data)
        else:
            self.leftChild = Node(data)
            return True

    else:
        if self.rightChild:
            return self.rightChild.insert(data)
        else:
            self.rightChild = Node(data)
            return True
```

however, he created a function with the same name in the tree class which looks like this

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.root:
            return self.root.insert(data)
        else:
            self.root = Node(data)
            return True
```

I do have some questions at this point, why are there 2 functions with the same name? and when I try to execute one of them without the other on this code it shows an error

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = Tree()
    tree.insert(10)
```

why does he made instance for tree not for node ?
can someone please explain those concepts for me, thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, often you can get along without the extra Tree class. Semantically, however, tree and node are two different concepts. Also, with only the node class you will have trouble representing an empty tree (at least a meaningful one that you can call methods on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you creating `tree` object it doesn't creating any node. It's just defining a `root` variable with `None`. Node is creating when you call `tree.insert()` method.

`insert()` method in `Tree` class is checking if `root` is `None` it creating a new `Node`. Otherwise it calling the insert method in `Node` class.

**Why does he made instance for tree not for node ?**

Because `insert()` method in `Node` class only handles the case where tree has atleast one node or tree is not empty. That's why he creating the instance of `Tree`.

Code with `insert()` method in `Tree` class:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, root, data):
        if root is None:
            self.root = Node(data)
        elif root.data < data:
            if root.rightChild is None:
                root.rightChild = Node(data)
            else:
                self.insert(root.rightChild, data)
        else:
            if root.leftChild is None:
                root.leftChild = Node(data)
            else:
                self.insert(root.leftChild, data)
```